The specified type 'Domain.Interfaces.IUser' must be a non-interface reference type to be used as an entity type
I have several projects in my solution for a .Net Core Web API. My ApplicationUser.cs which is in Infrastructure project looks like this:
using Domain.Interfaces;
using Domain.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace Infrastructure.Identity
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser, IUser
    {
        public string FullName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Product> CreatedProducts { get; set; }
    }
}

My Product.cs, which is in Domain project looks like this:
using Domain.Interfaces;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Domain.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        // ... Other properties

        [Required]
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual IUser User { get; set; }
    }
}

Domain isn't supposed to depend on Infrastructure, so I used an interface for Application User; which looks like this:
using Domain.Models;

namespace Domain.Interfaces
{
    public interface IUser
    {
        string Id { get; set; }
        string FullName { get; set; }
        ICollection<Product> CreatedProducts { get; set; }
    }
}

Here's my ApplicationDbContext as well:
using Domain.Models;
using Infrastructure.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Infrastructure.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            // ...
        }
    }
}

When I tried to add a migration, I got this error:

The property 'Product.User' is of an interface type ('IUser'). If it is a navigation, manually configure the relationship for this property by casting it to a mapped entity type. Otherwise, ignore the property using the [NotMapped] attribute or 'Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating

So I configured the relationship manually by adding this:
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
                .HasOne(p => p.User)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.UserId);

I still get this error:

The specified type 'Domain.Interfaces.IUser' must be a non-interface reference type to be used as an entity type.

Is there a solution for this? What do you guys recommend?

"What do you guys recommend?" changing public virtual IUser User { get; set; } to public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; } in the Product.

@GuruStron That doesn't work because I can't add a reference to Infrastructure from Domain

Then move ApplicationUser from Infrastructure to Domain.

@GuruStron Wouldn't that be against clean architecture? To be honest I'm doing this project as an entry test for a company and they insist on clean architecture. But if there's no other way I guess I have to do what you said.

"Wouldn't that be against clean architecture?" - why would it be, at least why would it be against more than Product already is? You already have Product in the domain and it's has attributes like ForeignKey which obviously non-domain level stuff. Either split domain models and entities completely or don't bother. P.S. without seeing the whole solution it would be hard to advise the best course of action.

@GuruStron Oh ok I'll do what you said then. Thank you so much for your time.

@GuruStron Here's the Github Link if you have the time to take a look
